# Is the lm-sensors project dead? www.lm-sensors.org doesn't load

Tags: sensors

I can't load the www.lm-sensors.org webpage.  I'm looking for documentation/information on lm-sensors to see if it is easy or hard to update it to detect Temper-USB thermometers.

It would be nice if we could get it to detect Temper-USB thermometers so we could chart it using PSensor.

Is the project dead?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/groeck/lm-sensors/issues/3) for a little more context.

Comment: Thanks Sato
Not sure why it has been voted down when in all respects, this is the ideal and probably the best place to ask such a question to get great answers and comments like yours and @Stephen Harris.

Comment: No, it isn't "ideal".  It's an answer that essentially benefits only you, and it will be obsolete in a few weeks either way, but it will still be archived and spamming search results for years to come.  [unix.se] is not the best site to search for the latest news about projects, you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site is down but the mailing list is active; http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.sensors/38361

Comment: I'm not sure why my question got voted down.  I'm not sure where else I could have gotten an answer like yours.  I reckon this place is the best place for such a question.
Thanks for you answer.